# Persisting user data across view controllers post-authentication

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm developing an (my first) iOS application, which utilizes a web service/data API that I've written. Users can create accounts and retrieve information using this API after they've logged in/been authenticated. All users have say a: username, user id, profile picture, biography, etc... I've created an NSObject "user" which is a class that has corresponding properties/attributes. After logging in, in each viewcontroller we need access to this user data, and the solution I've implemented for now is to give each viewcontroller a property "user" that expects my user object. Each time I instantiate a view controller, I am assigning the user class instance to the user property of the viewcontroller, so that I can access the properties of that instantiated user class from within the viewcontroller. I know that this not an optimal solution, but since I'm hacking along trying to learn iOS as I go, this is what I've run with for now.

My question is: What is the best way to persist this user data for use across multiple view controllers in my application?

Other notes: 
The amount of data that I need to persist is relatively little and is of types NSString, NSNumber, and UIImage. My user class is being instantiated for the current logged-in user, and also for other users for, for example, when retrieving data for a "friend" and then viewing their profile. Access to data for a user must be only if the user has been authenticated, so I need to be able to destroy the data-store once the session has expired.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to store the username, user id, profile picture, biography... locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

I'm not sure exactly how much data you are actually trying to store, but... there is an iOS wrapper to store small amounts of data locally in a plist called NSUserDefaults.
Its really easy to use. [Check out the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html)

It uses KVC to set/get the data.

Heres a simple example:

To save the data

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setString:myString forKey:@"username"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

To get it

```
_userName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                   stringForKey:@"username"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the user to be globally available you could store it on your app delegate as a public property. Something like:

In your AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSObject *user; // or User *user; if you have an actual user class
```

then in your view controllers

```
#import "AppDelegate.h" // at the top
[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.user; // where you need access to the user
```

Another route you could go down is a singleton class that holds your user in a property. For example:

```
@interface UserManager : NSObject
-(instancetype) sharedHandler;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSObject *user;
@end

@implementation UserManager
+(instancetype) sharedHandler
{
    static instancetype sharedInstance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
@end
```

A lot of people consider singletons and global properties as bad practice but I think they have their uses; they've simply been been abused and garnered a bad reputation. Another thing I should add is that this won't persist information between app launches (if the app is quit by the user or terminated by the system); unlike @NewEngland's answer which will. Good thing is you could actually use both ideas together if thats what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks Sean. I accepted the other answer since he responded first and the solution works well for me. I do very much appreciate your insight though. Thanks!